# SELECT TOP 1 is returning multiple records

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I shall link my database down below.

I have a query called 'TestMonday1' and what this does is return the student with the fewest 'NoOfFrees' and insert the result of the query into the lesson table. Running the query should help explain what i mean. The problem im having is my SQL code has 'SELECT TOP 1' yet if the query returns two students who have the same number of frees it returns both these records. Wit this being a timetable planner, it should only ever return one result, i shall also put the code below,

Many thanks

Code:

```
INSERT INTO Lesson ( StudentID, LessonStart, LessonEnd, DayOfWeek )
SELECT TOP 1 Availability.StudentID, Availability.StartTime, 
             Availability.EndTime, Availability.DayOfWeek
FROM Availability
WHERE 
  Availability.StartTime='16:00:00' AND 
  Availability.EndTime='18:00:00' AND 
  Availability.DayOfWeek='Monday' AND 
  LessonTaken IS NULL
ORDER BY 
  Availability.NoOfFrees;
```

Comment: That is what `TOP 1` in MS ACCESS does when there are ties for the `order by` keys.

Comment: Is there an alternative? As it needs to only return one record.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because Access returns all records in case of ties in `ORDER BY` (all records returned have the same values of fields used in `ORDER BY`).

You can add another field to `ORDER BY` to make sure there's no ties. `StudentID` looks like a good candidate (though I don't know your schema, replace with something else if it suits better):

```
ORDER BY 
  Availability.NoOfFrees, Availability.StudentID;
```

Comment: Hi there! This looks like a good idea, it doesnt matter too much as long as the end result is that it returns one record, will give it a go! Many thanks!

Comment: Yes this seems to have done the trick, I didnt realise that MS Access returned all the records if there was a tie like in this case, handy to know!