# Sub Query - Show Column B when Column C is Max of Group in Col A

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 columns (ID, Month, &  Qty).  ID column has multiple groups in it, and the Month goes from Jan-Dec and cycles through if there's enough values.  I'm trying to find the Max(Qty) of each ID group, and show the Month that Max occurred.  I'm trying to practice using Subqueries, so below is what I have so far...

SELECT t.ID, t.Month, t.Qty

FROM [Monthly Qty] t

WHERE t.Qty = (SELECT MAX(Qty) FROM [Monthly Production] m
   WHERE t.ID=m.ID);

Example of what I'm looking for is below. Starting with...

ID    Month    Qty

A     Jan      5

A     Feb      8

B     Sep      10

B     Oct      2

I would want my results to show...

ID    Month   Qty

A      Feb    8

B      Sep   10

Any help would be appreciated especially if it can be with a subquery, but if it's too much of a hastle I'll take whatever ya'll can give haha.

Comment: I'm using SQL in MS Acess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was faced with the same problem before and could not find a simple /fast solution as one would expect.

You can use select top 1 .... Order by Qt desc for each group.

```
SELECT JustATableWithEachGroup.id,
  (SELECT TOP 1 Mon FROM MonProd 
    WHERE id=JustATableWithEachGroup.id
    ORDER BY MonProd.Qty DESC) AS TopMonth,
  (SELECT TOP 1 Qty FROM MonProd
    WHERE id=JustATableWithEachGroup.id
    ORDER BY MonProd.Qty DESC) AS TopQuant
FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT MonProd.ID
  FROM MonProd)  AS JustATableWithEachGroup;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still having a little trouble with this. So far I have...

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still having some trouble with it.  I'm only using one table, so I'm not sure how I could use a LEFT JOIN with only one table. I tried to redo it as...SELECT ID1, Month1, Qty1 FROM (SELECT ID AS ID1, Month AS Month1, Qty AS Qty1 FROM [t1] GROUP BY ID) AS t1 .  Telling me now Month can't be used in a aggregate function, so I'm pretty sure I'm way off still.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited my first reply because it was not correct, I remembered the solution was not straitforward but it even a bit more complex.

Comment: Be carefull with naming something Month, it can be a reserved word.

Comment: Okay yeah I changed Month to Mon and that worked perfectly! Is there any way to increase the processing speed? Even if I need to modify the excel sheet it's linked to?  B/c I have over 200,000 entries with about 5,000 Unique IDs.  I haven't actually let it run through all 200,000 b/c it takes too long.  I just copied about 300 entries into another wkbk and it runs quickly, so I know it works.  I'm just wondering if there's anyway to increase the speed.

Comment: Most of the delay might come from using excell... If the table is imported try changing Id and Qty to Indexed:Yes (Duplicates OK). Having one Select Top 1 per Unique ID is not possible to escape and has some weigth, with some creativity you can try to use only one instead of 2...

Comment: Is that something I can do in the SQL Query or does it have to be done in the Design View?

Comment: Indexes are set in Design View

Comment: Okay, I was able to find that.  Now Access shows it running and once the bar is full and disappears nothing shows up.  Access then locks up like it's thinking.  So, I'm not sure if it's still thinking or what. But it's been frozen for going on 4 hours.  Any suggestions?  I have over 200,000 entries in the table.

Comment: hmm... 200,000 records shouldn't be such a problem. Make sure your 200,000 record table is imported and not just linked, use make table (INSERT INTO) to create a separate table with the Distinc GroupIDs.

Comment: Okay I can see it running faster, but sometimes I get an error that says, "At most one record can be returned by this query".  I use to be able to just close and then repoen and it'd work, but not this time.  Then all it'll return is the three columns with #Name? for a single record.  Any idea why that could be happening?

Comment: It seems to be having an issue with the Order BY

Comment: see SELECT TOP 1 is returning multiple records

Comment: link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773345/select-top-1-is-returning-multiple-records

Comment: That link helped perfectly! In the ORDER BY's I added MonPod.ID before the MonProd.Qty.  Thanks for the help! I learned a lot through this!

Comment: Not sure if you're going to see this, but do you know why it only works when my ID is Short Text?  Imported the excel sheet again, but changed my ID to a Number and now this wont work.